# How do I do a 301 redirect with RewriteRule using regex to change a word?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite my urls as follows:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/experiences/abc,123
http://www.mydomain.com/experience/abc,123
```

Basically I just need to drop the 's' in experiences. How the heck do I do this using RewriteRules with a 301 redirect?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why do people down-vote questions like this? I get that it's kind of a simple question, but regex is a nightmare if you don't know it. I'm trying and testing things right now, but if someone can get me an answer in the meantime that would be awesome and they get rep points!

Comment: Haven't read the question but I share the feeling that downvoting without leaving comment should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for mod_rewrite. Simply use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect 301 /experiences /experience
```

Comment: Really? Even with the stuff after the /

Comment: @SomethingOn: For basic cases mod_aliad might work. For ex: it won't work if somebody type mixed case URL like: `/experienceS/abc,123` or if OP wants to strip off query string from target.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^experiences/(.+)$ /experience/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```